# Pass a URL as paramater for AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

How can I pass a URL like "http://www.google.com" as a parameter for my AFNetworking POST request? I can try `[statusText.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"]` for the URL but when I retrieve my posted data for other purposes I get `http:////www.google.com` instead which would not be okay for me. Also, other texts might be affected by this method if a user sends a parameter with forward slash.

**EDIT**

The parameter is actually a text. Kinda like a tweet or FB status Im working with here. So users can enter a bunch of words and sentences and they can put URL as a string. When there is a URL, I get an error 500 on the webservice. But When I make it `http:////www.google.com` the error doesn't occur. So for example if a user sends a request with a parameter of `"Hello! Please check this website http://www.google.com"` I need to pass it to my request.

Comment: So your question is actually "how do I parse URLs from text?". How about [`NSDataDetector`](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/)?

Answer (score 0):

Just check using `hasPrefix` in `NSString`

```
NSString *strURL = @"http://www.google.com";
//Check if string contains http
if([strURL hasPrefix:@"http"])
{
    //Check if format is correct if not then make it correct
    if(![strURL hasPrefix:@"http://"])
    {
        strURL = [strURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http:/" withString:@"http://"];
    }
}
else //doesnot contain http 
{
    //Add http to string
    NSString *strTemp = [NSString stringWithString:strURL];
    strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",strTemp];
}

NSLog(@"%@",strURL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But I am working on a string that doesn't only contain a URL but a bunch of other words too. Please see my Edit.